# Session key for IOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an iOS app, and i want to access the currently logged in user's session key logged in onto the device. Is it possible to get session key of logged in user, in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token and expiration date. Why would you want that information?